# What would be the fastest algorithm to randomly select N items from a list based on weights distribution?

Tags: list, algorithm, sorting, math, random

I have a large list of items, each item has a weight.

I'd like to select N items randomly without replacement, while the items with more weight are more probable to be selected.

I'm looking for the most performing idea. Performance is paramount. Any ideas?

Comment: You should look at [Weighted_reservoir_sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Weighted_random_sampling)

Comment: [The Knapsack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) has no real solution within polynomial time.  But it is a well-explored idea.

Comment: With or without replacement?  If it's with replacement, you should look at the [alias method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_method), if it's without, look at reservoir sampling.

Comment: How much probablity?  With prob = 1.0 it is the N heaviest.  With prob = 0.0 just take first N.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Did you try different algorithms?  If so, were they fast enough for your purposes?

Comment: I need that algorithm without replacement. thank you!

Comment: Then you should translate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_A-ExpJ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling#Algorithm_A-Chao into the language of your choice (since you haven't told us what that is).  Both are O(M) to sample from a set of M items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to [sample items without replacement](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Weighted_Choice_Without_Replacement_Single_Copies), you have lots of options.

- Use a weighted-choice-with-replacement algorithm to choose random indices. There are [many algorithms like this](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Weighted_Choice). One of them is `WeightedChoice`, described later in this answer, and another is rejection sampling, described as follows. Assume that the highest weight is `max`, there are `n` weights, and each weight is 0 or greater. To choose an index in [0, `n`) using rejection sampling:

  1. Choose a uniform random integer `i` in [0, `n`).
  2. With probability `weights[i]/max`, return `i`. Otherwise, go to step 1. (For example, if all the weights are integers greater than 0, choose a uniform random integer in [1, `max`] and if that number is `weights[i]` or less, return `i`, or go to step 1 otherwise.)

  Each time the weighted choice algorithm chooses an index, set the weight for the chosen index to 0 to keep it from being chosen again. Or...
- Assign each index an exponentially distributed random number (with a rate equal to that index's weight), make a list of pairs assigning each number to an index, then sort that list by those numbers. Then take each item from first to last, in ascending order. This sorting can be done on-line using a *priority queue* data structure (a technique that leads to [*weighted reservoir sampling*](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Weighted_Choice_Without_Replacement_List_of_Unknown_Size)). Notice that the naïve way to generate the random number, `-ln(1-RNDU01())/weight`, where `RNDU01()` is a uniform random number in `[0, 1]`, is not robust, however ("[Index of Non-Uniform Distributions](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Index_of_Non_Uniform_Distributions)", under "Exponential distribution").
- Tim Vieira gives [additional options](https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2019/09/16/algorithms-for-sampling-without-replacement/) in his blog.
- A [paper](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/handle/1874/393383) by Bram van de Klundert compares various algorithms.

EDIT (Aug. 19): Note that for these solutions, the weight expresses how likely a given item will appear *first* in the sample. This weight is not necessarily the chance that a given sample of *n* items will include that item (that is, an *inclusion probability*). The methods given above will not necessarily ensure that a given item will appear in a random sample with probability proportional to its weight; for that, see "[Algorithms of sampling with equal or unequal probabilities](https://www.eustat.eus/productosServicios/52.1_Unequal_prob_sampling.pdf)".

---

Assuming you want to choose items at random with replacement, here is pseudocode implementing this kind of choice. Given a list of weights, it returns a random index (starting at 0), chosen with a probability proportional to its weight. This algorithm is a straightforward way to implement weighted choice. But if it's too slow for you, see my section "[Weighted Choice With Replacement](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Weighted_Choice)" for a survey of other algorithms.

```
METHOD WChoose(weights, value)
    // Choose the index according to the given value
    lastItem = size(weights) - 1
    runningValue = 0
    for i in 0...size(weights) - 1
       if weights[i] > 0
          newValue = runningValue + weights[i]
          lastItem = i
          // NOTE: Includes start, excludes end
          if value < newValue: break
          runningValue = newValue
       end
    end
    // If we didn't break above, this is a last
    // resort (might happen because rounding
    // error happened somehow)
    return lastItem
END METHOD

METHOD WeightedChoice(weights)
    return WChoose(weights, RNDINTEXC(Sum(weights)))
END METHOD
```

Comment: I like to think of it as Vose's variant of Walker's alias method, to give credit to the guy who had the original clever idea.

Answer (score 1):

Let `A` be the item array with `x` itens. The complexity of each method is defined as

> < preprocessing_time, querying_time >

---

**If sorting is possible: < O(x lg x), O(n) >**

1. sort `A` by the weight of the itens.
2. create an array `B`, for example:

   - `B = [ 0, 0, 0, x/2, x/2, x/2, x/2, x/2 ]`.
   - it's clear to see that `B` has a bigger probability from choosing `x/2`.
3. if you haven't picked `n` elements yet, choose a random element `e` from `B`.
4. pick a random element from `A` within the interval `e : x-1`.

---

**If iterating through the itens is possible: < O(x), O(tn) >**

1. iterate through `A` and find the average weight `w` of the elements.
2. define the maximum number of tries `t`.
3. try (at most `t` times) to pick a random number in `A` whose weight is bigger than `w`.

   - test for some `t` that gives you good/satisfactory results.

---

**If nothing above is possible: < O(1), O(tn) >**

1. define the maximum number of tries `t`.
2. if you haven't picked `n` elements yet, take `t` random elements in `A`.
3. pick the element with biggest value.

   - test for some `t` that gives you good/satisfactory results.

Comment: None of these solutions selects items with random distribution that matches the weights. These are just some (very inaccurate) approximations.