# Weighted random sample of array items *without replacement*

Tags: javascript, random, ecmascript-6

Javascript/ECMAScript 6 specific solution desired.

I want to generate a random sample from an array of objects using an array of weighted values for each object. The population list contains the actual members of the population - not the types of members. Once one is selected for a sample, it can't be selected again.

An analogous problem to the one I'm working on would be simulating a probable outcome for a chess tournament. Each player's rating would be their weight. A player can only place once (1st, 2nd, or 3rd place) per tournament.

To pick a likely list of the top 3 winners could look like:

```
let winners = wsample(chessPlayers,  // population
                      playerRatings, // weights
                      3);            // sample size
```

The weighted list may, or may not, be integer values. It could be floats like `[0.2, 0.1, 0.7, 0.3]`, or it could be integers like `[20, 10, 70, 30]`. The weights do not have to add up to a value that represents 100%.

Peter below gave me a good reference on a general algorithm, however It's not specific to JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62459274/7915759 it may be a good point of reference.

*Solutions to the problem that rely on generating a second population list with each member copied *weight* number of times may not be a practical solution. Each weight in the *weights* array could be very high numbers, or they could be fractional; basically, any non-negative value.*

Some additional questions:

- Is there already an `accumulate()` function available in JS?
- Is there a `bisect()` type function in JS that does a binary search of sorted lists?
- Are there any efficient and low memory footprint JS modules available with statistical functions that include solutions for the above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What would be the fastest algorithm to randomly select N items from a list based on weights distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455064/what-would-be-the-fastest-algorithm-to-randomly-select-n-items-from-a-list-based)

Comment: I'll take another look, but briefly scanning it, I thought the answer you linked may not be for JS, ECMAScript 6 (?)

Comment: The question applies to any programming language, not just JavaScript.

Comment: I got it. The algorithm discussed in the other answer is pretty similar to the above, I believe (having looked at it some more). It still leaves me with with some unsatisfied JS specific concerns though. Plus I think it's good to have a JS specific Q&A that has some code that can be easily pulled from by other JS devs in the future.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If this is working code and you just want comments on improving it, then you can take it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  But, only if it's already working.

Comment: Posting unfinished code may give you several creative solutions, maybe even some more efficient ones, but by "forcing" people to start with a given code base, they may not hit upon the most efficient algorithm. The problem is, the purpose of SO isn't to crowdsource the best overall algorithm; it's to give you a working (maybe better) algorithm from what you're starting with.

Comment: So what do you suggest @kmoser? Should I gut the body of the functions above and just leave a description of what I want them to do.. so others will have a hack at it?

Comment: Yes, it would make more sense to post a question and then your own answer.  Questions should be questions.  Answers should be answers.

Comment: Alright.. thanks @jfriend00.. I'll edit this to be in the format of purely a question.

Comment: The biggest inefficiency is calling `wchoice()` on every iteration (when trying to find multiples without replacement). Of course, if your list of weights is small, then this is a non-issue. I suggest you describe what particular situation you're trying to optimize for, before trying to just optimize in general.

Comment: This was a perfectly valid question, for which a Javascript solution wasn't already available on this site. The question was fixed so it wouldn't include any solution in it prior to being closed. So the format as a Q was correct. It's not clear to me the rationale behind closing it; voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following implementation selects `k` out of `n` elements, without replacement, with weighted probabilities, in O(n + k log n) by keeping the accumulated weights of the remaining elements in a [sum heap](https://timvieira.github.io/blog/post/2016/11/21/heaps-for-incremental-computation/):

```
function sample_without_replacement<T>(population: T[], weights: number[], sampleSize: number) {

    let size = 1;
    while (size < weights.length) {
        size = size << 1;
    }

    // construct a sum heap for the weights
    const root = 1;
    const w = [...new Array(size) as number[], ...weights, 0];
    for (let index = size - 1; index >= 1; index--) {
        const leftChild = index << 1;
        const rightChild = leftChild + 1;
        w[index] = (w[leftChild] || 0) + (w[rightChild] || 0);
    }

    // retrieves an element with weight-index r 
    // from the part of the heap rooted at index
    const retrieve = (r: number, index: number): T => {
        if (index >= size) {
            w[index] = 0;
            return population[index - size];
        } 
        
        const leftChild = index << 1;
        const rightChild = leftChild + 1;

        try {
            if (r <= w[leftChild]) {
                return retrieve(r, leftChild);
            } else {
                return retrieve(r - w[leftChild], rightChild);
            }
        } finally {
            w[index] = w[leftChild] + w[rightChild];
        }
    }

    // and now retrieve sampleSize random elements without replacement
    const result: T[] = [];
    for (let k = 0; k < sampleSize; k++) {
        result.push(retrieve(Math.random() * w[root], root));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code is written in TypeScript. You can transpile it to whatever version of EcmaScript you need in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

Test code:

```
const n = 1E7;
const k = n / 2;
const population: number[] = [];
const weight: number[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    population[i] = i;
    weight[i] = i;
}

console.log(`sampling ${k} of ${n} elments without replacement`);
const sample = sample_without_replacement(population, weight, k);
console.log(sample.slice(0, 100)); // logging everything takes forever on some consoles
console.log("Done")
```

Executed in Chrome, this samples 5 000 000 out of 10 000 000 entries in about 10 seconds.

Comment: What known algorithm did you model this after, and do you know if it's statistically accurate, or an approximation reservoir sample? If you have time, could you please add a few comments to the code to identify the different parts (heap insert, pop, etc)?

Comment: It's pretty much the same algorithm you use, except that I accumulate weights in a sum heap so I can update partial sums in O(log n) rather than O(n). The statistical distribution should therefore be identical. I added some comments and a link to a blog post explaining the technique.

Comment: hmmm.. I don't know how to get around updating all the subsequent accm weights after the current selection. I ran your code several times to analyze it, and your updates much fewer than mine even after I mod'd my code to reduce the accm wts updates. I'm not sure how a heap could reduce that overhead without missing some elements. Your code seems to produce valid results though =/

Comment: Then you should read the blog post I linked :-). The basic idea is that rather than calculating the sum from left to right, like `((((((a+b)+c)+d)+e)+f)+g)+h`, I calculate it like `((a+b)+(c+d))+((e+f)+(g+h))`.  This means that when an input changes, only O(log n) intermediary results are affected, allowing me to calculate the new sum quickly by keeping track of intermediary results. Also, I can use these intermediary results to quickly recalculate the O(log n) partial sums the binary search visits, bringing to overall runtime per element retrieved down to O(log n).

Comment: Yes.. I was just looking at that. Great reference - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**This is one approach, but not the most efficient.**

Its efficiency can be improved by using a [binary indexed tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) as its prefix sum.

The highest level function. It iterates `k` times, calling `wchoice()` each time. To remove the currently selected member from the population, I just set its weight to 0.

```
/**
 * Produces a weighted sample from `population` of size `k` without replacement.
 * 
 * @param {Object[]} population The population to select from.
 * @param {number[]} weights    The weighted values of the population.
 * @param {number}   k          The size of the sample to return.
 * @returns {[number[], Object[]]} An array of two arrays. The first holds the
 *                                 indices of the members in the sample, and
 *                                 the second holds the sample members.
 */
function wsample(population, weights, k) {
    let sample  = [];
    let indices = [];
    let index   = 0;
    let choice  = null;
    let acmwts  = accumulate(weights);

    for (let i=0; i < k; i++) {
        [index, choice] = wchoice(population, acmwts, true);
        sample.push(choice);
        indices.push(index);

        // The below updates the accumulated weights as if the member
        // at `index` has a weight of 0, eliminating it from future draws.
        // This portion could be optimized. See note below.
        let ndecr = weights[index];
        for (; index < acmwts.length; index++) {
            acmwts[index] -= ndecr;
        }
    }
    return [indices, sample];
}
```

The section of code above that updates the accumulated weights array is the point of inefficiency in the algorithm. Worst case it's `O(n - ?)` to update on every pass. Another solution here follows a similar algorithm to this, but uses a [binary indexed tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) to reduce the cost of updating the prefix sum to an `O(log n)` operation.

`wsample()` calls `wchoice()` which selects one member from the weighted list. `wchoice()` generates an array of cumulative weights, generates a random number from 0 to the total sum of the weights (last item in the cumulative weights list). Then finds its insertion point in the cumulative weights; which is the winner:

```
/**
 * Randomly selects a member of `population` weighting the probability each 
 * will be selected using `weights`. `accumulated` indicates whether `weights` 
 * is pre-accumulated, in which case it will skip its accumulation step.
 * 
 * @param {Object[]} population    The population to select from.
 * @param {number[]} weights       The weights of the population.
 * @param {boolean}  [accumulated] true if weights are pre-accumulated.
 *                                 Treated as false if not provided.
 * @returns {[number, Object]} An array with the selected member's index and 
 *                             the member itself.
 */
function wchoice(population, weights, accumulated) {
    let acm = (accumulated) ? weights : accumulate(weights);
    let rnd = Math.random() * acm[acm.length - 1];

    let idx = bisect_left(acm, rnd);

    return [idx, population[idx]];
}
```

Here's a JS implementation I adapted from the binary search algorithm from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

```
/**
 * Finds the left insertion point for `target` in array `arr`. Uses a binary
 * search algorithm.
 * 
 * @param {number[]} arr    A sorted ascending array.
 * @param {number}   target The target value.
 * @returns {number} The index in `arr` where `target` can be inserted to
 *                   preserve the order of the array.
 */
function bisect_left(arr, target) {
    let n = arr.length;
    let l = 0;
    let r = n - 1;
    while (l <= r) {
        let m = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);
        if (arr[m] < target) {
            l = m + 1;
        } else if (arr[m] >= target) {
            r = m - 1;
        } 
    }
    return l;
}
```

I wasn't able to find an accumulator function ready-made for JS, so I wrote a simple one myself.

```
/**
 * Generates an array of accumulated values for `numbers`.
 * e.g.: [1, 5, 2, 1, 5] --> [1, 6, 8, 9, 14]
 * 
 * @param {number[]} numbers The numbers to accumulate.
 * @returns {number[]} An array of accumulated values.
 */
function accumulate(numbers) {
    let accm  = [];
    let total = 0;
    for (let n of numbers) {
        total += n;
        accm.push(total)
    }
    return accm;
}
```

Comment: One optimization for updating the weights: when you select the element at position `i`, the only weights that need to be updated are at position `i+1` through `length-1`. So rather than updating *all* the weights every time you pick an element, just update the ones from `i+1` onward by decrementing them by `weights[i]`.

Comment: I've updated the solution to reduce some accumulate overhead @kmoser

Comment: This appears to have a runtime of O(kn), where k is the number of items in the sample, and n the number of items to be sampled from, which is hardly optimal. Even without employing fancy statistics, one can find an algorithm with O(n + k log n). Of course, whether that is worth it will depend on how large n and k are ...

Comment: See the answer I just posted.